# get kABAddressCountryCodeKey from address book

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, addressbook

I have this code to get the country of a specific person from my osx address book.

```
let address = person.value(forProperty: kABAddressProperty) as? ABMultiValue

print(((adresse?.value(at: 0) as? NSMutableDictionary)?.value(forKey: kABAddressCountryKey) as? String) ?? "No Country")

print(((adresse?.value(at: 0) as? NSMutableDictionary)?.value(forKey: kABAddressCountryCodeKey) as? String) ?? "No Country")
```

The print result for kABAddressCountryKey will be the complete country.
but I would like to have the country code key. But for the second print result I get "No Country"

what did I forget?

Comment: sry for this. english is not my primary language. i try my best ...

Comment: I change it in my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you forgot anything. I just iterated through my contacts, and of the 2,020 addresses I had with countries, 1,368 had no country code.

I just did a quick test and a contact added in macOS Sierra Contacts app did not get country code, whereas contact added in iOS 11 Contacts app did.